# How do I call a function from a Google Form from a different function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to run a function written in the context of the Google Sheets script editor that calls a different function written in the context of the Google Forms script editor. Is this possible?

Google Sheets

```js
function callForm() {
  /*something like this?*/
  formID.google.script.updateForm()
}
```

Google Forms

```js
function updateForm() {
  does stuff
}
```

I understand I can use triggers to run the form's script, but I'd like to do it from a google sheets script for a variety of reasons.

Comment: You will have to use the UrlFetchApp and Google Apps Script API but that might just add unnecessary complexity to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call an Apps Script function from a different Apps Script project, you can use the method [`scripts.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run). You only would need to fill the `function` parameter (and `parameters` if needed). To make that call you should use the [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch?hl=en). This approach would work as if the Apps Script API were a third party unrelated to your project, so you should handle the API authorization.